# How can I convert a JSON Array in form of string to a Lua table or parse it as JSON

Tags: json, lua

Couldn't find anything related to this, I have a field in my database which is the inventory data, I have this array as string form:

```
[{type:'item_standard',name:'hdlred',label:'Xenon Vermelho',weight:1,rare:0,can_remove:1,price:93,count:3},
{type:'item_standard',name:'hdlred',label:'Xenon Vermelho',weight:1,rare:0,can_remove:1,price:93,count:3},]
```

I wonder how I can convert that so then I can loop through every index (Lua), sorry for this newbie question but I really am mocking myself for this...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON String to Lua Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908199/convert-json-string-to-lua-table)

Comment: First convert the JSON to an object `JSON.parse(dataString)`

Comment: Why is the [javascript] tag?

Comment: @evolutionxbox The question is about Lua IIUC

Comment: Yes it's about Lua, and no @ChayimFriedman it doesn't solve my issue, I've looked into almost every topic google could come up with

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'll remove the JavaScript tag. 

Comment: @iCodeTits What was the problem with json-lua?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Hello, I can use it, I just get confused and if I do json.decode( inv.items ) it's a string still and json.decode( inv ).items is nil...

Comment: You should use `json:decode()`, but why `.items`?

Comment: It has to do how MySQL resource works on this, I select 'items' from table, then I have a callback which I do res[1].items to get the items, so .items is the JSON Array (string) I put above in the OP

Answer (score 0):

Here's an exmple using dkjson:

```
local json = require("dkjson")
local dataTable, pos, err = json.decode(yourstring)

if not dataTable then print(err) end
```

You might need to add some quotation marks around the keys in your json string though.