# bad argument #1 to 'for iterator' (table expected, got string)

Tags: lua, fivem

have a data like this

```lua
result = { 
    [1] = { ["identifier"] = MMK18495,["vehicles"] = {"vehN":"Caracara 4x4","vehM":"caracara2","totals":3},["id"] = 1,} ,
    [2] = { ["identifier"] = MMK18495,["vehicles"] = {"vehN":"Sandking SWB","vehM":"sandking2","totals":3},["id"] = 2,} ,
    [3] = { ["identifier"] = MMK18495,["vehicles"] = {"totals":5,"vehN":"Caracara 4x4","vehM":"caracara2"},["id"] = 3,} ,
    }
```

trying to sort this data to a menu like this

```lua
    for i=1, #result, 1 do
        local ownedcars = result[i].vehicles
        print(dump(ownedcars))
        for _,v in pairs(ownedcars) do  -- <- the error is here
            menu[#menu+1] = {
                header = " Model "..v.vehM.." Name "..v.vehN.." quantity"..v.totals,
                txt = "",
            }
        end
    end
```

the output of ownedcars

```
{"vehN":"Caracara 4x4","vehM":"caracara2","totals":3}
```

but here is the error
[image]

Comment: That is not a Lua table, looks like you have a string containing a json structure

Comment: this is LUA forget about menu table, how to sort vehicles for each ID ?
As a result, I would like to receive the following text.
id 1 vehicles vehM totals

```
vehM  caracara2 - totals 3
vehM sandking2 - totals 3
vehM  caracara2 - totals 5
```

Comment: You would need to decode the json string.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, this is not a Lua table. When inputting JSON tables, Lua reads them as strings. You will first need to convert your given JSON string into Lua. Thankfully, others have already done this. I will refer you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908199/convert-json-string-to-lua-table) which has answers that solved this problem.

Once you've converted your JSON string to a Lua table, you should be good to go.